# Dynamically generate PHP variables to populate morris.js charts from databases using codeigniter MVC

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, for-loop

Im using the codeigniter MVC latest release and im producing some reports from my databases, My problem is that if one of the admins add a new country I have to go into the CMS and manually add this country. Im trying to make this dynamic by creating variables from my table and then sending them to my output form, im currently generating an array of variables like so:

```
$vars = array();
$misc = 0;
$count = count($country_names);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    ${"var$i"} = 0;
    array_push($vars, ${"var$i"});
}
array_push($vars, $misc);
```

This gives me the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 [11] => 0 [12] => 0 [13] => 0 )
```

With `[13]` being the `$misc` variable, 
I now need to loop through a different table and match the countries to create a count of how many people in that county have used our service, I've tried this with no joy as the relevant variable count does not increase:

```
$misc = 0;
$count = count($country_names);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    ${"var$i"} = 0;
    array_push($vars, ${"var$i"});
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['country'] === "UK") {
            ${"var$i"}++;
        } else {
            $misc++;
        }
        array_push($vars, ${"var$i"});
    }
}
array_push($vars, $misc);
```

This code still gives me the same array output, any ideas? can i use a `foreach` loop inside a `for` loop? `$data` is an array sent from my `Search_model`:

```
$result->select('country')
    ->from('results')
    ->like('country', $countries)
    ->order_by('country', 'ASC');
$results = $result->get()->result_array();
return $results;
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of those variable variables? They're entirely superfluous and/or could be replaced by one array as far as I can see.

Comment: They are generated from the amount of entries in my countries table, so if we expand into another country(were exppanding quickly as were currently in 12 with plans to expand further) and I dont want to keep going into my code and modifying these, once I crack this the code will be re-used in other functions (tests taken, test names etc)

Comment: Whenever you think you need variable variables, what you really want is an array! Compare: `${"var$i"}++` vs. `$countries[$i]++`.

Comment: Hi, just tried `$countries[$i]++;` but none of the variable counts are increasing, the first index `[0]` should become 31 and misc `[13]` should be 3 as in my test database there are 31 patients from the uk and 3 from other countries. `$vars` is an array of variables

Comment: Forgot to reply sorry, you were both right, the answer was an array populated from a table in my database, in this case 'countries' I had the country name as the array index and assigned an initial value of 0 to each instance, then using a foreach loop to loop through a different table and increment the matching index by 1. Thank You. I will provide the answer with code when I get chance. Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, I used an array with the country names as an index and assigned an initial value of 0. Here is the code from my controller:

```
/* Create a string based on the countries array */
$new_country_names = array(); // An array of countries with numbers as indexes, EG: [0]=>Botswana etc
foreach ($country_names as $country) {
    $new_country_names[] = $country['name'];
}

/* Create a dynamic array of variables from the countries table, using the country name as the index EG: [UK]=>0 etc: */
$country_names_array = array(); // An array with country names as the index and 0 assigned to each one EG: [Botswana]=>0
foreach ($country_names as $country){
    $country_names_array[$country['name']] = 0;
}

/* Loop through each instance of the results table and create a count for all matching instances */
$misc = 0;
$countries_count = count($new_country_names);
$country_count = 0;
while($country_count < $countries_count) {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['country'] === $new_country_names[$country_count]) {
                                $country_names_array[$new_country_names[$country_count]] = $country_names_array[$new_country_names[$country_count]] + 1;
    } else {
            $misc++;
        }
    }
    $country_count++;
    }
$country_names_array = str_replace('_', ' ', $country_names_array); // Lose the underscores
$country_names_array = array_filter($country_names_array); // Filter out NULL values
$data = json_encode($country_names_array); // JSON encode the array to populate charts in the view
```

Here is a SS of the output with the chart & a print of the JSON data:

[image]

Big thanks to all who contributed